# SQL to LINQ duplicated group count

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, group-by

I am converting a SQL result to LINQ.

The SQL is simple:

```
select NAME, DESC, count(*) total from dbo.TBL_ITEM_BY_PROVIDER p 
inner join dbo.TBL_TYPE_PROVIDER tp on tp.id = p.provider_id
group by NAME, DESC SORT_ORDER
order by SORT_ORDER
```

The output is simple:

```
NAME    DESC                   Count(*)
CSD     Census and Statistics  5
LandsD  Lands Department       52
PlandD  Planning Department    29
```

My LINQ:

```
from p in data.TBL_ITEM_BY_PROVIDERs
join tp in data.TBL_TYPE_PROVIDERs on p.PROVIDER_ID equals tp.ID
group new { p, tp } by new { tp.NAME, tp.DESC } into provider
orderby (provider.Key.NAME)
select new { 
    provider.Key.NAME, 
    provider.Key.DESC, 
    count = (from pp in provider select pp.tp.NAME.ToList().Count())
};
```

and the output is a duplicated count array: `[5,5,5,5,5]`

```
0:{NAME: "CSD", DESC: "Census and Statistics", count: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]}
1:{NAME: "LandsD", DESC: "Lands Department", count: [52, 52, 52, 52...]}
2:{NAME: "PlandD", DESC: "Planning Department", count: [29, 29, 29, 29...]}
```

How to properly write a group statement like SQL?

Comment: are you using linq to entities? ie EntityFramework? What have you tried? Do you have any relevant class implementations?

Comment: I inheriting Controller Class and make use of System.Linq

I tried to select
count = (from pp in provider select pp.tp.NAME.Count()).FirstOrDefault()
but it still return an array with one element.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the grouping a bit differently. As you only want the count of how many items there are in the group you can just:

```
var result = from p in data.TBL_ITEM_BY_PROVIDERs
             join tp in data.TBL_TYPE_PROVIDERs on p.PROVIDER_ID equals tp.ID
             group 1 by new { tp.NAME, tp.DESC } into provider
             orderby provider.Key.NAME
             select new {
                 provider.Key.NAME, 
                 provider.Key.DESC, 
                 Count = provider.Count()
             };
```

Notice that the following does not do what you expect:

```
pp.tp.NAME.ToList().Count()
```

`NAME` is a string. Performing `ToList()` on it returns a `List<char>` so `Count()` on that counts the number of letters in the string. As you are doing in in the select statement of a nested query you get back a collection of the count, instead of a number.

Last, notice that in your sql your ordering is by `order by SORT_ORDER` and in your linq it is by `order by provider.Key.NAME` - Not the same field, and just by chance gives for this data the same desired ordering

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/group-clause), LINQ `group` clause returns a sequence of `IGrouping<TKey,TElement>`. While `IGrouping<TKey,TElement>` implements `IEnumerable<TElement>`, to calculate count of items in the group you can just call `Count()` method.

Also you can simplify `group` clause for your query.

```
from item in data.TBL_ITEM_BY_PROVIDERs
join provider in data.TBL_TYPE_PROVIDERs
    on item.PROVIDER_ID equals provider.ID
group item by provider into itemsByProvider
orderby itemsByProvider.Key.NAME
select new
{
    itemsByProvider.Key.NAME,
    itemsByProvider.Key.DESC,
    count = itemsByProvider.Count()
};
```